# Ascending chain condition on modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian

I have been having trouble with an exercise from Advanced Linear Algebra by Steven Roman, Chapter 5 exercise 6.

> Show that an $R$-module $M$ satisfies the ACC (ascending chain condition) for submodules if and only if the following condition holds. Every nonempty collection $\mathcal{S}$ of submodules of $M$ has a maximal element. That is, for every nonempty collection $\mathcal{S}$ of submodules of $M$ there is an $S \in \mathcal{S}$ with the property that $T \in \mathcal{S} \implies T \subseteq S$.

If the condition holds, the $M$ obvious satisfies the ACC because for an ascending chain $T_1 \subseteq T_2 \subseteq T_3 \dots$ we can take the sequence as a collection of submodules $\mathcal{S}$ which by condition has a maximal element $S$. This implies that the sequence stabilizes at $S$.

However, what is confusing me is the "if and only if". Every vector space is trivially a module, so if we look at $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-module, and take the collection of one-dimensional subspaces (which are also submodules), that collection doesn't satisfiy the maximal element condition, but $\mathbb{R}^2$ (as every finite dimensional vector space) does satisfy the ascending chain condition. This can be easily seen from the dimensions of the subspaces, $T_1 \subseteq T_2 \subseteq T_3 \dots \implies 0 \leq \text{dim} \; T_1 \leq \text{dim} \; T_2 \leq \text{dim} \; T_3 \leq \dots \leq 2,$ from which it follows that every such sequence does stabilize.

Comment: You are defining maxim**um**, not maxim**al**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That is, for every nonempty collection $\mathcal{S}$ of submodules of $M$ there is an $S \in \mathcal{S}$ with the property that $T \in \mathcal{S} \implies T \subseteq S$.

This is an incorrect definition of "maximal element," and you are right that your example disproves it.

The correct definition is something more like this:

> There is an $S\in \mathcal S$ with the property that if $S\subseteq T$ for some $T\in \mathcal S$, then $S=T$.

That is: nothing in $\mathcal S$ properly contains $S$.  With that correction, all of the one-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb R^2$ are maximal with respect to each other.

Now, as for the relation to the converse: Zorn's lemma says that if the ACC is satisfied like this for chains, then any nonempty subset has a maximal element. (With the 'correct' definition of maximal.)